# Finding the coding scheme for an optimum variable length code

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Suppose X is an i.i.d. r.v. with an infinite alphabet, X =
{1, 2, ...}. I also have P(X = i) = 2^{−i}

I want to find the coding scheme for an optimum variable length code however I don't follow the solutions coding scheme.

It appears that they have a 0 preceded by a 1 each time as you go down. Can someone please explain this to me.

For reference I have attached images/links of my question and solution as I am unsure of the policy of this website with not typing questions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPudG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLYGj.png

Comment: Please type in the question so it is self contained and useful to others. URLs can disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You get a prefix free code due to the pattern you mention.

Apply Huffman's algorithm to any finite truncation (you'd need to scale the probabilities but huffman doesn't care). For example

- A:1/2
- B:1/4
- C:1/8

would lead to B,C being merged giving the codewords, say,

- A:0
- B:10
- C:11

This argument may be extended to any finite length code source 
distribution $$(2^{-i})_{i=1}^n,$$ and also used to prove the achievability of the infinite 
expected codeword length of 2.